# Как добавить контент WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

В одном разделе есть три параграфа к примеру , каждый поставлен в свои цвета (красный , желный, оранжевый к примеру) и  тип каждому абзацу своё произвольное поле или как? я как то этого понять не могу. Или же идет текст и там внутри текста какой нибудь отрывок желтый и как это тогда изменять?

Comment: Какие такие "разделы"? Понятно опиши задачу. Можно даже нарисовать макет.

Comment: Раздел статьи. Есть заголовок и потом идет какое то содержание статьи  и один пораграф другого цвета... как этот цвет менять ?

Comment: используйте визуальный редактор, когда добавляете контент в статью. Там есть возможность изменить цвет текста

Comment: ok. а вот есть два параграфа , один из них weight 600..как это поставить?

Comment: В ВП нет никакого "раздела статьи".